# How to fix click simulation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click

I'm trying to simulate a click in a html page I have, but it only works after I click on Inspect element with the Chrome console

When I run the command in the console what I get is this

```
$('#toolbar-preview').click();
n.fn.init {context: document, selector: "#toolbar-preview"}
```

If I press inspect element the behaviour changes in

```
$('#toolbar-preview').click();
me.fn.init [a#toolbar-preview.link.icon-only]
```

and the buttons gets properly clicked from then on.

I'm not an expert at all in javascript so I don't know what the issue is about, is it maybe an initialization issue of the button?

EDIT
I don't know If I'm analyzing correctly, I think that what gets called is this, got this from the analyzing feature:

```
var g = function(e, t) {
        return t = null == t ? e.length - 1 : +t,
        function() {
            for (var i = Math.max(arguments.length - t, 0), a = Array(i), n = 0; n < i; n++)
                a[n] = arguments[n + t];
            switch (t) {
            case 0:
                return e.call(this, a);
            case 1:
                return e.call(this, arguments[0], a);
            case 2:
                return e.call(this, arguments[0], arguments[1], a)
            }
            var o = Array(t + 1);
            for (n = 0; n < t; n++)
                o[n] = arguments[n];
            return o[t] = a,
            e.apply(this, o)
        }
    }
```

and

```
on: function(e, i, a, n) {
                function o(e) {
                    var n = e.target;
                    if (t(n).is(i))
                        a.call(n, e);
                    else
                        for (var o = t(n).parents(), r = 0; r < o.length; r++)
                            t(o[r]).is(i) && a.call(o[r], e)
                }
                var r, s, l = e.split(" ");
                for (r = 0; r < this.length; r++)
                    if ("function" == typeof i || !1 === i)
                        for ("function" == typeof i && (a = arguments[1],
                        n = arguments[2] || !1),
                        s = 0; s < l.length; s++)
                            this[r].addEventListener(l[s], a, n);
                    else
                        for (s = 0; s < l.length; s++)
                            this[r].dom7LiveListeners || (this[r].dom7LiveListeners = []),
                            this[r].dom7LiveListeners.push({
                                listener: a,
                                liveListener: o
                            }),
                            this[r].addEventListener(l[s], o, n);
                return this
            }
```

I found the lines above following from here
[image]

EDIT2:
What I was able to understand for my issue is that it is caused by not having access to the iframe of the page. When I inspect an element the iframe gets exposed and then I can use queries and such to run commands like click. Is there a way to properly access an element inside the iframe with js? I have tried a couple of things but to no avail:

```
frameRef.contentWindow //I have no function to search for elements like "getElementById('')"
frameRef.contentWindow.document//this is null
frameRef.contentDocument//this is null
```

Comment: What does the click handler do?

Comment: Show the code for the click handler.

Comment: Add clarifications to the question, not comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try with :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#toolbar-preview').click();
  });
```

Comment: This has the same issue, only works after I have inspected the element once